# Bash script runs from php command line but not from page

Tags: php, bash, apache, shell, raspbian

I have a bash script that works as expected from both the shell and the PHP command line, but not when called from a PHP page in Apache (Raspbian). I.e, this works (PHP command line):

```
>php exec('/var/www/html/scripts/myBashScript.sh');
```

But this doesn't (index.php):

```
<?php
exec('/var/www/html/scripts/myBashScript.sh');
?>
```

No error messages are displayed and I can't see anything relevant in the Apache server logs. As suggested by other responses, I've also tried:

- exec('sh /var/www/html/scripts/myBashScript.sh')
- exec('./scripts/myBashScript.sh')
- exec('sh ./scripts/myBashScript.sh')

Both script file and its containing folder have rwx permissions for the Apache user (www-data). The script is set to executable. Built-in bash commands work as expected from the php file, i.e. this works:

```
<?php
echo exec('whoami');
?>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: How do you know it's not running? Use the [`$output` and `$return_var` arguments](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and `var_dump` what they contain. Also if it's a bash script, trying to run it with `sh` instead of `bash` seems silly.

Comment: @FuzzyTree: -rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 396 Apr  9 11:02 scripts/myBashScript.sh

Comment: @Alexander, the script launches a web browser so I know this is not happening. It generates no other output.

Comment: Do something simpler to start debugging, like a simple echo, or writing a file.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Same issue with a script file containing only an echo.

Comment: Did you use the `$output` and `$return_var` arguments and `var_dump` them? What do they contain? The one should give you the exit code at least.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara you are right: var_dump returns the echo string for $output and int(0) for $return_var, so the script does execute. But it only executes built-in Bash commands.

Comment: Well, the script does execute, so maybe try rewriting the question to address what exactly does not work in the script.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be related to non-Bash commands in the scripts rather than to the script itself. See comments above. Thank you @AlexanderO'Mara.